# Checking permissions using Webservices in Liferay 6.2

Tags: web-services, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to consume liferay web services.
I want to **check whether a user has permission(add/update/delete) on a resource** but I didn't find any method to do that.

I found that liferay implemented permission checking inside the web service methods.
In this way I can show an error message when a user try to perform an action on which he don't have permission.

But I think it's better to not to allow him instead of showing error message.

**For ex:**
A user don't have permission to add document.
Webservice call will throw an exception when he tries to add a document.
In my view hiding the add button is better than showing an error.

Comment: You may create your own custom-webservices to check if user has permission on any resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    PermissionChecker permissionChecker = getPermissionChecker();

    if(!permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, permissionModelKey, groupId, permissionKey))
            throw new PortalException("You don't have the required permissions!");
```

Where `permissionModelKey` is the model-name of your resource (ex: `com.your.namespace.model.YourClass`) and permissionKey is a action-key, that may be defined in your `resource-actions/default.xml`.

Use this as the first lines of `YourClassServiceImpl` service method and if the user doesn't have the right permission (don't test it with admin user) it will throw a `PortalException`. Or if you rather, you can do a graceful exit. It depends only of the way you want to treat that use case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't fulfill my requirement. Can you please once again read the example mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no time to elaborate, but you can use `hasResourcePermission` from `ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil` in order to solve your issue:

```
public static boolean hasResourcePermission(long companyId,
                                            String name,
                                            int scope,
                                            String primKey,
                                            long roleId,
                                            String actionId)
                                     throws PortalException,
                                            SystemException
```

Returns true if the role has permission at the scope to perform the action on resources of the type.

Depending on the scope, the value of primKey will have different meanings. For more information, see ResourcePermissionImpl.

```
Parameters:
companyId - the primary key of the company
name - the resource's name, which can be either a class name or a portlet ID
scope - the scope
primKey - the primary key
roleId - the primary key of the role
actionId - the action ID
Returns:
true if the role has permission to perform the action on the resource; false otherwise
Throws:
PortalException - if a role with the primary key or a resource action with the name and action ID could not be found
SystemException - if a system exception occurred
```

Link to javadocs: [hasResourcePermission](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.html#hasResourcePermission(long,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I created a new web service method and called hasResourcePermission from CustomEntityServiceImpl class.